# How to keep focus on more than one window for input devices

Tags: c#, input

The idea is to do something like what a keystroke catcher does, but with multiple input devices. I want a window to record input from devices even if the focus is on another window. What libraries or methodologies would allow me to accomplish this?

Comment: What research have you done on this yet?

Comment: [This is what you need](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804/en-us has the basic idea, but when you click on another window the hook stops tracking. I need the window to continue grabbing data even when the window loses focus.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically handled via a [low level Hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  There is no C# library which will handle this directly, though there is a Microsoft KB article showing [How to set a Windows hook in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804/en-us).

Comment: If you click on a different window the hook stops tracking. That's not what i'm going for, i've already found this article and should have mentioned that, sorry.

Comment: @superradish That's a normal hook - you need a low level hook - read about hooks in the first link I posted, and you should see how to adapt the article to making them.  Only mouse + keyboard LL hooks will work from C#, though.

Comment: That's fine, all i need is the mouse and keyboard

Comment: @superradish Here's another example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook